# Consuming SOAP complexType webservice with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, complextype

Ok guys, something bothering me for days. I have some WebService with a *comlextype* that I need to consume in PHP.

Webservice look something like this:

```
<s:element name="VerifySession">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:VerificationRequest"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="VerificationRequest">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SessionKey" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ApplicationID" type="s1:guid"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

I tried to solve the problem with a different approach, currently my code looks like this

```
try {
  $info = $soapClient->__call("SignIn", array($ap_param));
  $search_query = new StdClass();
  $search_query->oVerificationRequest = new StdClass();
  $search_query->oVerificationRequest->SessionKey = $token;
  $search_query->oVerificationRequest->ApplicationID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";

  $info = $soapClient -> VerifySession($search_query);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {  
      echo "ERROR" .$fault;
}
```

`$token` value is already known, so there is no problem there.

Comment: how to write correct code? because you're always get exception some thing like this: "exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: First step with trouble-shooting is, you make the error message visible in your question as such. Also the error normally carries a line number, highlight where in your code-example the error occurs. This will make it more visible to other users reading your question what you're actually concerned about. For the "how to write correct code?" question, that generally asked, it's also generally answerd: Write correct code. So better make clear what specifically you're interested in. Otherwise it's hard for other users to follow you.